# How make file system listing in Java Swing

Tags: java

I need to index the whole file system, and then convert to xml. So I created the code, but it produce the out of memory error (heap). So my question is how to avoid this error. Is it due creating File1 object or the vector is too match I have set the virtual memory something but it again produce the error at 973.

`

```
import java.util.Vector;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
public class Filewalk {
Vector<File1> vs= new Vector<File1>();
public void walk( String path ) {
File root = new File( path );
File[] list = root.listFiles();
if (list == null) return;
for ( File f : list ) {
if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
walk( f.getAbsolutePath() );
}
else {
File1 fv=new File1(f.getAbsoluteFile().toString(),f.length()); --we could change for the next string--
//mainRootElement.appendChild(getFile (doc, num++, f.getName(), f.length(), f.getAbsoluteFile());//
}
}
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
Filewalk fw = new Filewalk();
File [] disks = File.listRoots();
for ( File d : disks )
fw.walk(d.toString());
//ByteArrayInputStream baos = new ByteArrayInputStream();
//ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(baos);
//oos.writeObject(fw.vs);
//oos.close();
}
}
class File1 {
File1 (String path1, long size1)
{ this.path=path1; this.size=size1;}
String path;
long size;}
```

`

```
Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.list(Native Method)
at java.io.File.list(File.java:973)
at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1051)
at listing.Filewalk.walk(Filewalk.java:8)
at listing.Filewalk.walk(Filewalk.java:12)
at listing.Filewalk.walk(Filewalk.java:12)
at listing.Filewalk.walk(Filewalk.java:12)
at listing.Filewalk.walk(Filewalk.java:12)
```

at listing.Filewalk.main(Filewalk.java:24)

I try to create this big vector to pass it into swing Jtable to show at least some part of file(autonumber, name, size, path). Anyway during the uindexing I need to assign this unique number and to save it  to something. Maybe I need to use direct writing to JDBC table through the add the record to absolve the memory issues? Anyway If I would like to convert such properties to xml tag I also need to save this big xml file to search after in it by name these files. How to resolve this issue? Is it idea of vector of all File1's correct? How much space could take the whole indexing?

Comment: You (and probably most people) have too many files on their file system to build one huge list.  If you want to list the files on your system, you're going to have to use a JTree for the display and do a breath first search of all the files at the first, second, and third levels of your file system.  As the user opens branches of the JTree, you walk down a level at that tree node.

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/DisplayafilesysteminaJTreeview.htm -- I see this example, and other ones byt could I generate the whole file tree in such way. And what about out of memory error and why on 973 line or so.

Comment: at java.io.File.list(File.java:973)
at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java) – waht this strings means. Why always on (File.java:973)?
So why do vector is not filled, meanwhile in the example --http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/DisplayafilesysteminaJTreeview.htm –there is also vector.
If it possible to use the whole file system listing or indexing in one Jtree?
And what about converting to XML? Should I use Jtree for it?

Comment: Can anybody try to run my code at his PC file system? I would like to know what is the reason of memory error and compare with my one.

Comment: And in any case I should also convert this properties file Index, name, path, size to xml. It is not difficult to do even using this code -- but I need to save this xml anywhere and probably memory issues will arise too. I need to save as I need to search by tag file name the files. And there is also the question -- could I display this xml long file in swing (for example in textarea, at least partially)?

Comment: Why don't you try with small list of files and check if your code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Can we propose something like that. I just added the inserting records for aforementioned code. It is due to avoid memory crash by adding every file property to created database. But I do not know can we use in SQL STATEMENT the variables. especially created by using such one as f.method(). Id possible to avoid complexities we could craete to nethods from the second code --one for creating DB and table and the second for inserting records and in this way we could include just methods.
And of cause I do not know jow to properly shape try and catch rules for this JDBC pieces of code.

```
`import java.sql.*;
  import java.io.File;
 public class Filewalk {
 int i=0;
 static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";   
 static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/STUDENTS"; 
  static final String USER = "root"; 
 static final String PASS = "";

 Connection conn = null; 
 Statement stmt = null;
  //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver 
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 

  //STEP 3: Open a connection 
  System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database..."); 
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS); 
  System.out.println("Connected database successfully..."); 

  //STEP 4: Execute a query 
  System.out.println("Creating table in given database..."); 
  stmt = conn.createStatement(); 

  String sq = "CREATE DATABASE FILESS"; 
  stmt.executeUpdate(sq); 

  String sql1 = "CREATE TABLE SYSTEM1 " + 
               "(id INTEGER not NULL, " + 
               " name VARCHAR(255), " +  
               " path VARCHAR(255), " +  
               " size INTEGER, " +  
               " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";  
  stmt.executeUpdate(sql1); 


  public void walk( String path ) {
  File root = new File( path );
  File[] list = root.listFiles();
 if (list == null) return;
 for ( File f : list ) {
 if ( f.isDirectory() ) {
  walk( f.getAbsolutePath() );
 }
 else {
 String sql2 = "INSERT INTO SYSTEM1" + 
 "VALUES (i++,f.getName(), f.getAbsoluteFile().toString(),f.length())"; 
 stmt.executeUpdate(sql2);
}
}

try{ 
     if(stmt!=null) 
        conn.close(); 
  }catch(SQLException se){ 
  }// do nothing 
  try{ 
     if(conn!=null) 
        conn.close(); 
  }catch(SQLException se){ 
     se.printStackTrace(); 
  }//end finally try
     }//end try 
 System.out.println("Goodbye!"); 
}//end main 


}
public static void main(String[] args) {
Filewalk fw = new Filewalk();
File [] disks = File.listRoots();
for ( File d : disks )
fw.walk(d.toString());
}
}
`
```

Answer (score 0):

> People tell me what the reason is in error?

Simple.  Your application is trying to use more heap memory than the JVM has.  That is because it is trying to create a huge in-memory `Vector` containing info about all files in the file system.

> How many files this app could process until the ceasing,

That depends on how big the heap is.  That in turn depends on the Java heap size parameters.  Read the manual entry for the `java` command, paying attention to the `-xmx` and `-xms` parameters.

However, that doesn't solve the problem. No matter how big you make the heap, if the file system is large enough your application is going to crash.  Your approach of loading all of the data into a big `Vector` will not work.  Period.

Instead, you should implement your own custom `TableModel` class that lazy-loads by querying the database of tree-walk results as required... and *doesn't* keep that information in memory after it has been used.

But even that is a bad idea (IMO).  Displaying a file system to a user as a scrollable 2-D table with thousands or millions of entries is a horrible UI design. A better idea would be to use a `JTree` ... with a suitable lazy-loading "model" class to avoid building a huge in-memory data structure.

Better still, use an existing file-tree widget like `JFileChooser` ... and don't reinvent the wheel.